# Relation extraction using StanfordNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

As part of a Question Answering System I am trying to do relation extraction using StanfordNLP via the Java API. I can assume that I get input sentences of the form    and I want to return the relation as a String. So far I have been trying to do the following:
- I have used "openie" with mixed results.
- I  have been trying to use the class RelationExtractorAnnotator directly. It contains a main but it's execution doesn't terminate. If a construct my own main and use the class inside of it it doesn't terminate either.

Are there other options I should consider to solve this problem? Why does RelationExtractorAnnotator not terminate?

Comment: The simplest thing is to build a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline in your code and annotate the sentence.  You can use the openie extractor to get the relations.  Full example code is at this link: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html